# [file].dat into readable file in JAVA

Tags: java, encode, filereader

I am trying to read the content of a .dat file into JAVA, I know that it should content alphanumeric characters, but when I apply my method to read it, I can only see special characters. I guess that there a way to encode the .dat characters into human readable characters that I can't find out.

```
String textFile = "C:(...).dat";



BufferedReader reader = null;
BufferedReader reader2 = null;
String line = "";
String line2 = "";
String textSplitBy = ";";

try{
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(textFile);

    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(textFile));
    reader2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        String[] test = line.split(textSplitBy);

        line2 = reader2.readLine();

    }
}catch (FileNotFoundException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}catch (IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The object line and line2 give the exact same result :

url=http://postimg.org/image/oi4w9h8d1/

Comment: Where is the .dat file coming from? E.g if a MSFT winmail.dat file this gets a whole lot more complicated.  If your own file, can you provide a quick sample of what the file contains?

Comment: What encoding does the dat file has? Who is producing this dat files? Can you provide an example dat file data?

Comment: If the file is binary you shouldn't be using a Reader at all, you should be using an InputStream.

Comment: They content financial data translated into alphanumeric, the pdf file that they transmitted to me contain only what correspondance in term of alphanumeric that I can't see right now !